# Ошибка при установке APK

Tags: android, apk

При установке APK возникают 2 ошибки:

```
DEXOPT_FAILED
UID_CHANGED
```

Лог небольшой:

```
07-10 11:14:22.581 D/AndroidRuntime(9964): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
07-10 11:14:22.601 W/ActivityManager(391): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///storage/emulated/0/AppProjects/HashcodeClient/bin/HashcodeClient.apk
07-10 11:14:22.621 I/PackageManager(391): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl-1984616986
07-10 11:14:22.781 W/PackageManager(391): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/ru.hcc-1.apk
07-10 11:14:22.911 D/AndroidRuntime(9964): Shutting down VM
```

Если ставить через рут, то лог такой:

```
07-10 11:14:23.141 D/AIDE    (9795): pm:    pkg: /storage/emulated/0/AppProjects/HashcodeClient/bin/HashcodeClient.apk
07-10 11:14:23.141 D/AIDE    (9795): pm: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]
07-10 11:14:23.141 D/AIDE    (9795): pm: exited with 0
```

Что я пытался делать: ставил через стандартный установщик, ставил через рут, чистил проект, чистил глубины /data/, пересобирал с другим keystore, 8(!) раз перезагружал девайс, менял имя пакета.

Но именно моё приложение не хочет устанавливаться - другие пакеты спокойно обрабатываются установщиком. На stackoverflow прочёл, что поможет Wipe Data через Recovery, но жалко другие мои данные. Как избавиться от этих ошибок и до конца поставить APK?

***Update #1*** смог получить более подробный [лог](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAqCN.png).

***Update #2*** Наконец-то смог исправить ошибку. Так как DalvikVM ругался на "L;", то я собрал APK, но не установил его, а через APKTool достал smali-код. Далее с помощью редактора я нашёл тот самый "L;", потом удалил из bin/classes2/ этот файл и программа установилась нормально.

И да, вот та самая функция, из-за которой установка не удавалась. Может быть, мне кто-нибудь объяснит, в чём ошибка :)

```
private Object getLast(Editable text, Class kind) {
    Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);
    if(objs.length == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        for (int i=objs.length; i > 0; i--) {
            if(text.getSpanFlags(objs[i-1]) == Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK) {
                return objs[i-1];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Логи в студию

Comment: @Barmaley, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @SuperCreeper что-то не вижу здесь

>DEXOPT_FAILED
>UID_CHANGED

Это тогда откуда?

Comment: @Barmaley, извините, не дописал ро установку через root. Если что, DEXOPT_FAILED выходт если ставить после очистки /data/ от мусора.

Answer (score 2):

У вас где-то осталась ссылка на `UID` приложения (обычно после ручного удаления аппы). `UID` создается при установке приложения и записывается в файле `/data/system/packages.xml` - удалите в нем запись о пакете своего приложения. Может поможет.

Comment: @Barmaley, записи о моём приложении в этом файле нет. Скорее всего я испортил проект, когда удалил папку /bin и скомпилировал заново.

Comment: Такое ощущение что у вас нет прав на запись на `/storage/emulated/0/AppProjects/HashcodeClient/bin/` - попробуйте `chmod 775` на этот каталог или установите через `adb`

Comment: @Barmaley, не помогло. Отправил apk другу, если у него не установится, то значит я испортил проект. Позже отпишусь.

Comment: @Barmaley, у друга такая же ошибка. Уже не знаю, что делать :(

Answer (score -1):

Мне помогло удаление папки `/data/data/[название вашего приложение]`.

После удаления приложения бывает, что она остается.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?