# Как исправить INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT?

Tags: android, java

Решил попробовать использовать в своем приложении баннер от Smaato. Собрал приложение, все работает. Но внезапно всплыла проблема: оказывается, приложение перестало устанавливаться на старых Android устройствах (проверено на 2.3 и 2.1). В LogCat примерно следующее:

```
12-05 21:35:01.755: E/dalvikvm(11220): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=52
12-05 21:35:03.165: E/installd(32): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@vmdl36109.tmp@classes.dex' res = 11
```

В консоли это:

```
[2014-12-06 01:25:09 - MyApp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
```

Не работает ни отладка, ни установка из APK. Если убрать библиотеку Smaato, то начинает собираться нормально. В проекте есть и другие библиотеки.
Я так понимаю, это глюк ОС и связан он не с конкретной библиотекой, а с превышением какого-то лимита. Как его можно исправить?

Вот полный лог, если необходимо:

```
12-05 21:34:36.706: D/installd(32): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/vmdl36109.tmp' ---
12-05 21:34:45.835: D/dalvikvm(11220): Note: class Lcom/google/android/gms/games/internal/IGamesService$Stub; has 186 unimplemented (abstract) methods
12-05 21:34:47.306: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.fullScreenIntent
12-05 21:34:47.316: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/app/Notification;.actions
12-05 21:34:47.796: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
12-05 21:34:47.806: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/graphics/BitmapFactory$Options;.inMutable
12-05 21:34:48.166: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
12-05 21:34:48.166: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
12-05 21:34:53.465: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
12-05 21:34:56.135: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
12-05 21:34:56.225: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
12-05 21:35:00.495: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
12-05 21:35:00.625: D/dalvikvm(11220): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
12-05 21:35:01.755: E/dalvikvm(11220): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=52
12-05 21:35:01.765: E/dalvikvm(11220): VM aborting
12-05 21:35:01.866: I/DEBUG(28): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-05 21:35:01.875: I/DEBUG(28): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.1-update1/ECLAIR/35983:eng/test-keys'
12-05 21:35:01.891: I/DEBUG(28): pid: 11220, tid: 11220  >>> /system/bin/dexopt <<<
12-05 21:35:01.891: I/DEBUG(28): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
12-05 21:35:01.897: I/DEBUG(28):  r0 00000354  r1 afe1331d  r2 0000000c  r3 deadd00d
12-05 21:35:01.897: I/DEBUG(28):  r4 00000026  r5 ad07ff50  r6 004fffd4  r7 0050000c
12-05 21:35:01.897: I/DEBUG(28):  r8 00000000  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 00000000
12-05 21:35:01.897: I/DEBUG(28):  ip ad080160  sp bedbf7d0  lr afe142dd  pc ad035452  cpsr 20000030
12-05 21:35:01.955: I/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc 00035452  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:01.965: I/DEBUG(28):          #01  pc 0003c994  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:01.965: I/DEBUG(28):          #02  pc 00057936  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:01.965: I/DEBUG(28):          #03  pc 00057c26  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:01.975: I/DEBUG(28):          #04  pc 000583b4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:01.975: I/DEBUG(28):          #05  pc 000585c6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:01.995: I/DEBUG(28):          #06  pc 00057eac  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:01.995: I/DEBUG(28):          #07  pc 0005972e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.019: I/DEBUG(28):          #08  pc 000587a4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.045: I/DEBUG(28):          #09  pc 0005840c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.065: I/DEBUG(28):          #10  pc 000585c6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.126: I/DEBUG(28):          #11  pc 00057eac  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.165: I/DEBUG(28):          #12  pc 000450f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.216: I/DEBUG(28):          #13  pc 00047954  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.236: I/DEBUG(28):          #14  pc 00048e1c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.266: I/DEBUG(28):          #15  pc 0004905a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.316: I/DEBUG(28):          #16  pc 0004b4a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.416: I/DEBUG(28):          #17  pc 0004b52a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.436: I/DEBUG(28):          #18  pc 0004b5d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.495: I/DEBUG(28):          #19  pc 0004a57c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.576: I/DEBUG(28):          #20  pc 0004a72e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.596: I/DEBUG(28):          #21  pc 00008a84  /system/bin/dexopt
12-05 21:35:02.615: I/DEBUG(28):          #22  pc 00008bd4  /system/bin/dexopt
12-05 21:35:02.626: I/DEBUG(28):          #23  pc 00008eba  /system/bin/dexopt
12-05 21:35:02.656: I/DEBUG(28):          #24  pc 0000c2c6  /system/lib/libc.so
12-05 21:35:02.676: I/DEBUG(28):          #25  pc b00018aa  /system/bin/linker
12-05 21:35:02.726: I/DEBUG(28): code around pc:
12-05 21:35:02.746: I/DEBUG(28): ad035440 4808ecb6 6b9b5823 d0002b00 4b064798 
12-05 21:35:02.758: I/DEBUG(28): ad035450 701c2426 ed28f7d9 0004ab1c fffe57c4 
12-05 21:35:02.766: I/DEBUG(28): ad035460 fffe8c30 00000354 deadd00d b510b40e 
12-05 21:35:02.795: I/DEBUG(28): code around lr:
12-05 21:35:02.806: I/DEBUG(28): afe142cc 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
12-05 21:35:02.816: I/DEBUG(28): afe142dc 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
12-05 21:35:02.826: I/DEBUG(28): afe142ec bdf01c30 00024b44 000000b4 1c0fb5f0 
12-05 21:35:02.826: I/DEBUG(28): stack:
12-05 21:35:02.835: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf790  406ee758  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/0 (deleted)
12-05 21:35:02.845: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf794  406ee758  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/0 (deleted)
12-05 21:35:02.866: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf798  afe3902c  /system/lib/libc.so
12-05 21:35:02.866: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf79c  afe38fd8  /system/lib/libc.so
12-05 21:35:02.866: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7a0  00000000  
12-05 21:35:02.886: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7a4  afe142dd  /system/lib/libc.so
12-05 21:35:02.916: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7a8  406ee758  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/0 (deleted)
12-05 21:35:02.926: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7ac  afe1331d  /system/lib/libc.so
12-05 21:35:02.936: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7b0  000137ec  [heap]
12-05 21:35:02.936: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7b4  ad07ff50  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.945: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7b8  ad07ff50  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:02.956: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7bc  004fffd4  
12-05 21:35:02.966: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7c0  0050000c  
12-05 21:35:02.976: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7c4  afe1337f  /system/lib/libc.so
12-05 21:35:02.985: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7c8  df002777  
12-05 21:35:02.985: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7cc  e3a070ad  
12-05 21:35:02.996: I/DEBUG(28): #00 bedbf7d0  000137e8  [heap]
12-05 21:35:02.996: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7d4  ad03c999  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:03.006: I/DEBUG(28): #01 bedbf7d8  00000034  
12-05 21:35:03.016: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7dc  00000000  
12-05 21:35:03.025: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7e0  00000034  
12-05 21:35:03.025: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7e4  ad017314  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:03.025: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7e8  000137ec  [heap]
12-05 21:35:03.036: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7ec  00000004  
12-05 21:35:03.056: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7f0  ad080c8c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:03.056: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7f4  406ee758  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/0 (deleted)
12-05 21:35:03.056: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7f8  41f91f1e  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
12-05 21:35:03.066: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf7fc  00018368  [heap]
12-05 21:35:03.066: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf800  41cab860  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
12-05 21:35:03.066: I/DEBUG(28):     bedbf804  ad05793b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-05 21:35:03.165: W/installd(32): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/vmdl36109.tmp' --- status=0x000b, process failed
12-05 21:35:03.165: E/installd(32): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@vmdl36109.tmp@classes.dex' res = 11
12-05 21:35:03.208: W/PackageManager(110): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/ru.bartwell.myapp.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же ошибка несколько месяцев назад, [посмотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/334528/android-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-apk)

Исправил, очистив и пересобрав проект. Также ищите методы, которые написали перед появлением ошибки, DexOpt частенько не пережёвывает `return null`.

Comment: К сожалению, очистка и пересборка не помогает. Новых методов перед появлением не добавлял, добавлял только Smaato в медиацию MoPub (библиотека и класс-адаптер). Соответственно, если их убираю, то все работает хорошо. Собрал отдельный тестовый проект, только с медиацией и этой библиотекой - тоже все работает хорошо. На https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/30900/ вроде обсуждают какой-то патч (не понял как применять) и на http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html динамическую загрузку библиотек. Думал, может попроще какое-то решение есть.